# How to get remote file size without Content-Length[C++]

Tags: c++, libcurl

Get remote file size without content length.

```
size_t readHeader(char* header, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata) {
// this works I get the file size when Content-length is available
        if (startsWith(header, "Content-Length:")) {
        std::string header_in_string = replaceAll(header, "Content-Length:", "");
        long size = atol(header_in_string.c_str());
        *file_size = size; 
    }
    else { // do something else }
    return size * nitems;
}
// main function
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(temp_file_name, "wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./ca-bundle.crt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, this);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, readHeader);
    // writing the downloading content to file
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

This provide the solution in C# via GET
[Getting remote file size without content-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897972/getting-remote-file-size-without-content-length) but I want to know the solution in C++ with libcurl.

Comment: Which language are you using here?  You've tagged with the whole neighborhood.  Note that the `Content-Length` header may not always be present or reliable.  Sometimes, you may have to read the entire stream to find out the true length.

Comment: I am using C++ here. What do you mean by read the entire stream? Are you referring to download the whole file. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Lucif yes, "read entire stream" means download the file.

Comment: That article you referenced said nothing of getting the length of the content without the content-length header.